# jquery max validation not working

Tags: jquery, validation

I have used jQuery validation but max is not working.

```js
$("#tax").validate({
  // Specify the validation rules
  rules: {
    igst: {
      digits: true,
      max: 2
    }
  },
  // Specify the validation error messages
  messages: {
    igst: {
      digits: "Please enter a valid number.",
      max: "Please enter a value less than or equal to 2."
    }
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    form.submit();
  }
});
```

Comment: Any error in your browser console? Please provide more code like HTML and full jQuery code

Comment: Could you share your html code so we have an working example ?

Comment: Please click the `<>` and create a snippet with a [mcve]

Comment: Try to put more code also your browser console messages

Comment: <label class="control-label">IGST Percent<span class="required">*</span> </label>
 <?php echo $this->Form->input('igst',['type'=>'text','required'=>true,'div'=>false,'label'=>false,'class'=>'form-control','default'=>$data['igst']])?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confused with what `max` is for. It means that the value of the `igst` field has to be a number less than or equal to 2 (0, 1, 2)

https://jsfiddle.net/xzua16f8/

If I am not wrong, what you are looking for is `maxlength`, which means the number could be anything not more than 2 digits.

https://jsfiddle.net/xzua16f8/1/

Anyway, the `max` and `maxlength` both works fine, you can check the fiddles.

Comment: Thanks @Faisal Umair

Comment: No issues. I am glad, I could help. But your question was not on point, please make sure you explain what the issue is as others have mentioned in the question comments and provide something which can reproduce the error (if you have any questions in future). I was only able to guess by the field name "igst".

Comment: Wow, I literally wandered about an hour before I found this. Thank you sooo much.